# Change focus via KeyListener when switch between tabs in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtabbedpane, key-events

What I planned to do is when I press `Enter` key, the application will fire up the button `btn_teach`, and switch to another tab with `textfield` focused. Now, when I implement it, it works perfectly **if** I press the button manually (not pressing `Enter`). When I actually press `Enter`, the tab switches back but the text field on that tab is not focused.

`tp` being `JTabbedPane`.
My plan is to switch from tab index 1 to tab index 0 and set `txt_send` focused

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String say = txt_saypane.getText();
        String ans = txt_anspane.getText();
        //this.clear();

        say = say.replace("\n","");
        ans = ans.replace("\n","");

        this.talk(this.botTeach(say,ans), false);

        tp.setSelectedIndex(0);
}

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int sel = tp.getSelectedIndex();
    if(sel == 0)
        txt_send.requestFocusInWindow();
    if(sel == 1)
        txt_saypane.requestFocusInWindow();
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
            {

                if(txt_saypane.isFocusOwner() || txt_anspane.isFocusOwner())
                    btn_teach.doClick();
            }
    }
```

What is the correct way to change focus via `KeyListener` when switching between tabs in `JTabbedPane`?

Comment: Seems like pressing ENTER key alone is the real catch here. I had tried every possible way I knew of, to achieve this, but it seems like you have to use Some another key in conjunction with ENTER key to get the desired result. Don't know whether it's a bug, since never faced this in the past. Do try focusButton.addMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); as described in my latest edit, that gives the desired result. But when ENTER key is used alone, seems like something else is at work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `JButton` to work on press of the `ENTER` key you can make that `JButton` to be your `DEFAULT Button` on frame, instead of using `KeyEvents`. You can do this by writing :

```
yourFrameObject.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(btn_teach);
```

Writing this line will also make this JButton work on pressing the ENTER key, without you writing the whole KeyListener part for it. Remove the `KeyListeners` from this `JButton`. Once this `JButton` is the `DEFAULT Button`, now on Pressing the `ENTER` key, it will do the work that is written inside it's actionPerformed() method.

Don't use KeyEvents with Swing, that belongs to awt, [KeyBinding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) is what we use with Swing.

Here is one sample program to help your cause :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ButtonTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private JButton focusButton;
    private JPanel contentPane, tab1, tab2;
    private JTextField textField1, textField2, textField3;

    public ButtonTest()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        tab1 = new JPanel();
        textField1 = new JTextField(10);
        textField1.requestFocusInWindow();
        tab1.add(textField1);

        tab2 = new JPanel();
        textField2 = new JTextField(10);
        textField3 = new JTextField(10);
        tab2.add(textField2);
        tab2.add(textField3);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP,
                                                JTabbedPane.WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT);
        tabbedPane.addTab("TAB 1", null, tab1, "I am TAB 1");
        tabbedPane.addTab("TAB 2", null, tab2, "I am TAB 2");

        focusButton = new JButton("CHANGE FOCUS");
        //focusButton.addMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); /* You can Add this Line too
                                                      /* , to make it work. But here
                                                       * you have to press ALT + ENTER.
                                                       */
        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(focusButton);
        focusButton.addActionListener(this);

        contentPane.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(focusButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        if (tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex() == 0)
        {
            tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(1);
            textField3.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
        else if (tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex() == 1)
        {
            tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(0);
            textField1.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new ButtonTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```